# select and read an XML file (client-side)

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

What would be the best way to read an xml file and displaying for a user? I want to solve this on the client side. I was thinking either browsing files using activeX (they will be using IE) and loading the content with jQuery ajax, or using a input type=file if its possible. What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ascending order of monstrosity:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- Flash
- Java Applet

Comment: This is correct, but i used activeX, since everyone will be using IE(7) in this case.

Comment: Heh, ActiveX was off the scale :)

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery And Ajax
Here is a  sample script that I used for learning purposes,

[IT IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/DJ9E4/12/)

And here is a [Tutorial](http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX has built in parsers. You just need to put in the final parameter what you want, like:

```
$.post(url, params, function(data) { bla bla }, "xml");
```